# Sum of Time Duration Not Aggregating past 24 Hours in "hh:mm:ss" format in Power Bi Visual Table

Tags: powerbi, dax

The data comes over as Duration within seconds as a data type Whole Number. I then convert this over to a "hh:mm:ss" through various calculations. I then make my new "hh:mm:ss" column into a [Sum of measure]. When I put this measure into a table it doesn't sum pass 24 hours.

```
Sum of Return
04:50:26
05:20:44
22:54:00
14:01:07
13:29:43
18:43:46
08:47:34
09:55:51
```

Total 02:03:11

Total Should be : 98:03:11 <-- This total is needed

These are the Columns

```
Hours = INT([duration]/3600)
```

```
Minutes = INT(MOD([duration]-([Hours]*3600),3600)/60)
```

```
Seconds = roundup(mod(mod([duration]-([Hours]*3600),3600),60),0)
```

```
VAR H = if(len([Hours])=1,CONCATENATE("0",[Hours]),CONCATENATE("",[Hours]))
```

```
VAR M = IF(LEN([Minutes])=1,CONCATENATE("0",[Minutes]),CONCATENATE("",[Minutes]))
```

```
VAR S = IF(LEN([Seconds])=1,CONCATENATE("0",[Seconds]),CONCATENATE("",[Seconds]))
```

```
RETURN = CONCATENATE([VAR H],CONCATENATE(":",CONCATENATE([VAR M],CONCATENATE(":",[VAR S]))))
```

Measure Formula:

```
Return = SUMX('Query1',[Return])
```

The actual total sum of the duration hours to be 98:03:11 in the visualization.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've edited your post to add code blocks. Can you confirm that you in fact have three columns, each named [VAR H], [VAR M], [VAR S], and a fourth named [Return]? And that [Return] is a column holding text? How do you sum a text column?

Comment: Hey Greggy thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the column seconds into the number of seconds in a day, in a new calculated column.

```
Hours = divide([Seconds],86400)
```

After that, you need to change the data type of the column to Time for the same calculated column.

[image]

Finally, you can create a Measure for summing up the hours

```
Hours_Sum = sum(Table[Hours])
```

And change the data type of the measure to **hh:mm:ss**

[image]

In my case, I had **16,150** seconds representing **4:29:10**

[image]

The table I've used was

```
+---------+
| Seconds |
+---------+
|     334 |
|      96 |
|    1607 |
|    1056 |
|    1355 |
|     551 |
|    1928 |
|     767 |
|     601 |
|    1214 |
|     607 |
|    1873 |
|     519 |
|     537 |
|     686 |
|     138 |
|     439 |
|    1842 |
+---------+
```